# Wordpress 5.0 REST API posts/{ID} return 404 status

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

I am new to Wordpress and do not actually understand what I am doing wrong. I have installed advanced ads plugin, which sore ads information in the wp_posts table. wp_posts table used to store regular blog articles, which can be retrieved via API 
but when I am trying to get a record for ads plugin (which use the same wp_posts table), I am getting 404.

Example:
123 is post_id for regular post
domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/123  will return JSON information about an article

456 is a post_id for ads records (which stored in the same table where 123 is)
domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/456 will return this json:

```js
{
  "code":"rest_post_invalid_id"
  ,"message":"\u041d\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439 ID \u0437\u0430\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0438."
  ,"data":{"status":404}
}
```

any ideas on how to get information from the wp_posts table via REST API?

Comment: The post is probably private (e.g. the column `post_status` is `private`), or that the post type is not `post` - and if so, the post type may have not been enabled for the WP REST API. The other possible reason, is that there's a plugin or code which *excludes* the post from the REST API response.

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks for your reply, you are right - post_type field is not "post", it is "adv" and when I change it to "post" API return correct info. Do you know how to  configure WP REST API? I need update it to return any post_type by ID

Comment: Actually, if it's a custom post type, then the route is different: `/wp/v2/{rest_base}/<id>` - e.g. `/wp/v2/adv/456`. The `{rest_base}` defaults to the post type slug unless changed when the post type is registered. If that route doesn't work, then the post type is likely not enabled in the REST API.

Comment: I mean, try `domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/adv/456` (note the `adv` and not `posts` in the URL). (PS: In my first comment, just ignore the sentence "*- and if so, the post type may...*". Sorry about that.)

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks you a lot! I've googled some info about REST API and found wordpress plugin which allows me to enable custom endpoint.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: would you, please improve your q and answer with your custom endpoint? :)